# Paypal Express checkout showing old site instead of new

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I am trying to setup Paypal express checkout for my website, and I have managed to get it to work, however I have noticed that on some websites you appear to get the new style of Paypal, but on mine I appear to be getting the old.

New style that I want:
[image: The Paypal I want]

The style that I'm getting:
[image: My Paypal]

I want to be able to set one or more items as part of the invoice, as well as always having a payment fee and booking fee, as in the first picture above.

When making the initial call to Paypal to get a token to setup the express checkout I am passing the following in the query string.

```
USER: username,
PWD: password,
SIGNATURE: signature,
VERSION: 117.0,
ALLOWNOTE: 0,
METHOD: 'SetExpressCheckout',
RETURNURL: returnUrl,
CANCELURL: cancelUrl,
NOSHIPPING: '1',
LOCALCODE: 'GB',
EMAIL: 'test@test.com',
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT: '20.00',
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE: 'GBP',
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION: 'Sale',
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT: '2.00',
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT: '22.00',

L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0: 'Physical',
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0: 'Journey 1',
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0: '20.00',
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0: '1'
```

I can't work out why my one is showing the old site instead of the new one.
I have tested this with both the sandbox and live version of Paypal and getting the same thing, so I presume it is either something wrong with my Paypal account setup or the parameters I am passing in the initial express checkout setup?

The urls I am using are: `https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com` for the initial connection, and `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=TOKEN_RETURNED` for the redirect that I send the user to after getting a token.

I have also seen live websites using both the old version and the new version of Paypal.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new pages are something they're slowly rolling out.  Even the same site will see both versions sometimes.  It's just a random thing they've got set happening on their end.  For example, they may be pushing 50% of all Express Checkout transactions through the new pages while pushing the other 50% through the old pages to split test them against each other.  I don't know if that's the exact thing they're doing, but it's just an example.  It's not anything you'll be able to control.

Comment: Oh, that's a bit annoying. Hopefully it will be done by the time I launch the site. Also do you know what parameters I have to use to get the same setup as in the first picture? Do I just use 4 items one for each payment, and one each for the payment fee and booking fee, as the `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT` is not actually postage and packaging as it has appeared in the second picture.

Comment: You could include those as line items, sure. Then they should show up exactly as you label them.  Handling is technically part of shipping (hence the phrase Shipping & Handling) so that's why they show it like they do.  Looks like that could very well be one of the things they're split testing.